# Lógica de desenvolvimento de um teclado virtual em c

Tags: c, ascii

Eu crio um `array` contendo os 127 caracteres `ascii` eg `list(char(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...))` e adiciono um identificador com cada tecla com cada item da lista - correspondente a seus respectivos valores.

Implemento as funções `ALFA NUMERICO` e `LOWERCASE` no programa, crio uma interface gráfica e coloco para rodar dentro de um `loop`.

A lógica do programa seria essa, acho que eu conseguiria desenvolver um protótipo em *Python*, mas, **gostaria de um exemplo em c**.

quem quiser coperar vou deixar o link do repositorio do [github](https://github.com/sandkmz/vkey)

Comment: Acho que precisarias de fazer qualquer coisa com threads [(artigo na Wikipedia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29). De qualquer maneira talvez prefirar fazer esse projecto numa linguagem mais moderna, com facilidades inerentes para GUI.

Comment: quais linguagens mais modernas serião essas? e em relacao aos threads eu vou levar em consideracao o comentario

Comment: acho que vou criar um projeto no github para hospedar o compartilhar com a galera o processo de desenvolvimento

Comment: @ed1rac esse tipo de edição que você fez é totalmente desencorajada. Edições podem melhorar ou consertar a formatação do post, mas não pode adicionar ou alterar o sentido do que o autor disse. Sempre opte por comentar e orientar o autor que ele mesmo faça essa edição.